# Mysql how to sum column with previous column sum

Tags: mysql, sql, math, xls

In XLS I have two columns A and B.

```
A,B

1,1
2,3
2,5
1,6
5,11
2,13
```

A column have value, and B column is calculated with formula, (A + (previous row B value))

How can i do this calculation on MYSQL?

I'm trying to join same table twice and i can get previous rows A column next to B.

I can sum them, but how can I sum them with this formula?

XLS formula looks like this:

```
H20 = H19+G20
```

This is my SQL created from suggestions.

```
SELECT 
    date, time, sum, @b := sum+@b as 'AccSum', count 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        t.date, t.time, t.sum, t.count 
    FROM TMP_DATA_CALC t 
    ORDER BY t.epoch) as tb
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @b := 0) AS var
;
```

Comment: Please post the MySQL query you are using to get the output.  It can be done with a join against a subquery, maybe, if you have a specific `ORDER BY` that will reliably return the same sort.  Otherwise, SQL result rows have no knowledge or relationship to the rows which precede or succeed them. Each row is an entity unto itself, though you may have applied a sort.  So a dynamic spreadsheet isn't really a good correlate to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A, @b := A+@b AS B
FROM (SELECT A
      FROM YourTable
      ORDER BY id) AS t
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @b := 0) AS var
```

The user variable `@b` holds the value of `B` from the previous row, allowing you to add the current row's `A` to it.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f66f8a/1)

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74488/2/1 shows how to select the data.

```
SET @runtot:=0;
Select a,b, @runtot:=@runtot+a from b
```

However there's an underlying problem I can't figure out.  Since you don't have a defined order, the SQL could do this ordering in any way, so you may not get the desired results..  without a defined order you results may be unpredictable.

runtot = running total.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL we don't have any  function like partition by which Oracle has. You can use curser  to achieve your requirement. Or we can write any function which will get rownumber as input then add these two values then return that to query.

select b from xsl limit rownum-1,1 + select a from xsl limit rownum,1